# How to use `.netrc` file in coursier fetch/launch

Tags: coursier

I have very simple need of launching jar which has all dependencies burned in and main class configured. The only thing which I need to do is fetch, *cache* (this is important because jar is large) and launch and I want to do all of this with one liner.

Coursier works just fine till the point when it needs to go through auth:

```
...
unauthorized: https://
...
```

I already have .netrc configured and I wonder if there is an option for coursier to use credentials from there (curl and python can do that).

Alternatively, is there way to explicitly pass credentials to repository via command line?